# validate form field on tab change

Tags: javascript, validation, tabs

I have two tabs with different fields. One is sign-up with email,name and password fields the other is for login with username and password field. The form action will point to same servlet page. So how will i validate those two tabs accordingly?

```
<form name="form" action="RegisterServlet" method="post" onsubmit ="return validate()" >
<div class="login-wrap">
<div class="login-html">
    <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab" >Sign In</label>
    <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Sign Up</label>
    <div class="login-form">
        <div class="sign-in-htm">
            <div class="group">
                <label for="user1" class="label">Username</label>
                <input id="user1" name="username1" type="text" class="input" >
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="pass1" class="label">Password</label>
                <input id="pass1" name="password1" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" >
            </div>
            <span style="color:red"><%=(request.getAttribute("errMessage") == null) ? ""
 : request.getAttribute("errMessage")%></span>

            <div class="group">
                <input type="submit" name="ACTION" class="button" value="Login" >
            </div>
            <div class="hr"></div>
            <div class="foot-lnk">
                <a href="RegisterServlet?action=forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-up-htm">
            <div class="group">
                <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
                <input id="user" name="username" type="text" class="input" >
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
                <input id="pass" name="password" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" >
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="email" class="label">Email Address</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="input" >
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <input type="submit" name="ACTION" class="button" value="Register" >
            </div>
            <div class="hr"></div>
            <div class="foot-lnk">
                <label for="tab-1">Already Member?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add signup and login in two different form tags. They can point to the same servlet page but you will know which button is clicked and then you can perform your functionality accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add onchange handlers for radio buttons and make sure desired
   form is visible
2. Add validate method for form onsubmit handler.

Hope this helps.

```js
function onChangeSignIn() {
  var signIn = document.getElementsByClassName("sign-in-htm");
  signIn[0].classList.remove("disable");
  var signUp = document.getElementsByClassName("sign-up-htm");
  signUp[0].classList.add("disable");
}

function onChangeSignUp() {
  var signIn = document.getElementsByClassName("sign-in-htm");
  signIn[0].classList.add("disable");
  var signUp = document.getElementsByClassName("sign-up-htm");
  signUp[0].classList.remove("disable");
}

function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById("tab-1").checked) {
    console.log('on tab-1 - sign-in')
    // do validation for tab-1 fields
    const user1 = document.getElementById("user1").value;
    if (user1 === "") {
       console.log("Username is empty in sign-in, please enter");
       return false;
    }
  }

  if (document.getElementById("tab-2").checked) {
    console.log('on tab-2 - sign-up')
    // do validation for tab-2 fields
    const user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    if (user === "") {
       console.log("Username is empty in sign-up, please enter");
       return false
    }
  }

  return false; // or true based on validation
}

onChangeSignIn();
```

```css
.disable {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="RegisterServlet" method="post" onsubmit ="return validate()" >
<div class="login-wrap">
<div class="login-html">
    <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in"  onchange="onChangeSignIn()" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab" >Sign In</label>
    <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up" onchange="onChangeSignUp()"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Sign Up</label>
    <div class="login-form">
        <div class="sign-in-htm">
            <div class="group">
                <label for="user1" class="label">Username</label>
                <input id="user1" name="username1" type="text" class="input" >
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="pass1" class="label">Password</label>
                <input id="pass1" name="password1" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" >
            </div>
            <span style="color:red"><%=(request.getAttribute("errMessage") == null) ? ""
 : request.getAttribute("errMessage")%></span>

            <div class="group">
                <input type="submit" name="ACTION" class="button" value="Login" >
            </div>
            <div class="hr"></div>
            <div class="foot-lnk">
                <a href="RegisterServlet?action=forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-up-htm">
            <div class="group">
                <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
                <input id="user" name="username" type="text" class="input" >
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
                <input id="pass" name="password" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" >
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="email" class="label">Email Address</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="input" >
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <input type="submit" name="ACTION" class="button" value="Register" >
            </div>
            <div class="hr"></div>
            <div class="foot-lnk">
                <label for="tab-1">Already Member?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```